# Where to find data on Australian business types and locations?

Tags: data-request, business, australia

There are numerous Australian government websites which manage businesses, including:

- [Australian Business Register](https://abr.gov.au/)
- [Australian Securities and Investments Commission](http://asic.gov.au/)
- [Business.gov.au](http://www.business.gov.au/Pages/default.aspx)
- [ABN lookup webservice](http://abr.business.gov.au/Webservices.aspx)

However, I can't see any datasets which show the **location and business type** of Australian businesses.

The closest I've found is the [ABN Bulk Extract](http://data.gov.au/dataset/abn-bulk-extract) dataset on data.gov.au, which shows the business name and postcode, but no information on the business type (eg, is it a pharmacy or a donut shop?).

Are there any publicly available datasets showing the Name, Type and Location of businesses across Australia? (Either free or paid is fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any free datasets which answered my question.

But the next best thing was a reasonably cheap dataset from http://datajet.com.au which had business name, type and lat/long:

[image]